# Already defined in Date.obj cpp Class

Tags: c++, class, object, defined

Trying to get my class working, however it's saying I've already defined my functions, when I have only declared them.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9wialxvcVA for what I am trying to achieve.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

//main.cpp    The main file 

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Date.cpp"


int main(){

    int mm, hh;

    cout << "Enter the Hours integer" << endl;
    cin >> hh;
    cout << "Enter the Minutes integer" << endl;
    cin >> mm;

    Date firstD(hh, mm);

    cout << "The hours is " << firstD.getHours() << endl << "The minutes are " << firstD.getMinutes() << endl;

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;

}

------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Date.cpp   The definitions of the methods

////Function Definitions
#include "Date.h"

Date::Date(){
    m = 0;
    h = 0;
}

Date::Date(int hh, int mm){
    m = mm;
    h = mm;
}

Date::~Date(){

}

int Date::getMinutes() const{
    return m;
}

int Date::getHours() const{
    return h;
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Date.h       declaring methods and properties

//Header

#ifndef Date_h
#define Date_h

class Date{

public:
    //default constructor
    Date();

    //overload constructor
    Date(int, int);

    //destructor 
    ~Date();

    //accessor methods
    int getMinutes() const;
    int getHours() const;

private:

    //member variables
    int h;
    int m;

};

#endif
```

Note, "std_lib_facilities.h" is a header file acting as a library of useful code to help with compiling e.g   etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing `#include "Date.cpp"` to `#include "Date.h"` will probably fix your problem.

Comment: Yes! worked like a charm! 

What is wrong with including the Date.cpp which includes the Date.h? 

And how does main.cpp pick up Date.cpp now?  Thanks again!

Comment: When you use `#include "Date.cpp"`, the function definitions are compiled into object code twice -- once when compiling `Date.cpp` and again when compiling `main.cpp`.

Comment: You probably build with `Date.cpp` as a separate translation unit, then including that in another source file will cause *two* copies of everything to be in the object files.

Comment: Thanks! I can now crack on with my university coursework, thanks guys.

Comment: @JoalGate Just remember: `.h` files are for `#including`; `.cpp` files are for compiling. :)